# Como inserir uma propriedade em um objeto javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Tenho o seguinte objeto javascript:

```
  data2 = 
    {
      "desColigada": "Empresa fulano de tal",
      "codMatricula": "00555454",
      "dataImpressao": "23/05/2016"
    };
```

Preciso saber como inserir esse array no objeto acima:

```
arrayInformacoes = 
  [
    {
      Data: "Mar 20, 2017 12:00:00 AM", 
      Atividade: " 23 GERAR", 
      Observação: "Processo cancelado por: Administrador - as", 
      Usuário: "afo"
     }
  ]
```

Comment: Já experimentaste `data2.arrayInformacoes = arrayInformacoes;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como JavaScript é completamente dinâmico, é possível criar a propriedade "*on the fly*", assim: `data2.arrayInformacoes = arrayInformacoes;`

```js
var data2 = {
  "desColigada": "Empresa fulano de tal",
  "codMatricula": "00555454",
  "dataImpressao": "23/05/2016"
};

var arrayInformacoes = 
  [
    {
      Data: "Mar 20, 2017 12:00:00 AM", 
      Atividade: " 23 GERAR", 
      Observação: "Processo cancelado por: Administrador - as", 
      Usuário: "afo"
     }
  ];

data2.arrayInformacoes = arrayInformacoes;

console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode unir ambos objectos assim:

```
data2 = 
    {
      "desColigada": "Empresa fulano de tal",
      "codMatricula": "00555454",
      "dataImpressao": "23/05/2016"
    };

arrayInformacoes = 
  [
    {
      Data: "Mar 20, 2017 12:00:00 AM", 
      Atividade: " 23 GERAR", 
      Observação: "Processo cancelado por: Administrador - as", 
      Usuário: "afo"
     }
  ];

var s = Object.assign(data2, arrayInformacoes[0]); 
// ou
var y = Object.assign(data2, {arrayInformacoes}); 
// ou
Object.assign(data2, {arrayInformacoes});


console.log(s);
console.log(y.arrayInformacoes[0]);
console.log(data2);
```

Comment: Único porém dessa solução é que você não atualiza o objeto existente, você gera um novo. Bacana para programação funcional, mas foge um pouco da pergunta.

Comment: @LeandroOriente depende, pode-se copiar para objecto existente.

Comment: É, nesse caso ele além de retornar o objeto está mutando o primeiro parâmetro né. Mas mutação por mutação é mais simples adicionar direto na propriedade né?

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayInformacoes = 
  [
    {
      Data: "Mar 20, 2017 12:00:00 AM", 
      Atividade: " 23 GERAR", 
      Observação: "Processo cancelado por: Administrador - as", 
      Usuário: "afo"
     }
  ]


data2 = 
    {
      "desColigada": "Empresa fulano de tal",
      "codMatricula": "00555454",
      "dataImpressao": "23/05/2016",
      "ArrayInformacoes":arrayInformacoes   
    };
```

ou

```
data2.ArrayInformacoes = arrayInformacoes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar uma nova propriedade em um objeto javascript basta usar a seguinte sintaxe:

```js
var data2 = {
  "desColigada": "Empresa fulano de tal",
  "codMatricula": "00555454",
  "dataImpressao": "23/05/2016"
};

data2.arrayInformacoes = [
  {
    Data: "Mar 20, 2017 12:00:00 AM", 
    Atividade: " 23 GERAR", 
    Observação: "Processo cancelado por: Administrador - as", 
    Usuário: "afo"
   }
];
```

ou

```js
var data2 = {
  "desColigada": "Empresa fulano de tal",
  "codMatricula": "00555454",
  "dataImpressao": "23/05/2016"
};

var arrayInformacoes = [
  {
    Data: "Mar 20, 2017 12:00:00 AM", 
    Atividade: " 23 GERAR", 
    Observação: "Processo cancelado por: Administrador - as", 
    Usuário: "afo"
   }
];

data2.arrayInformacoes = arrayInformacoes;
```

Ambos vão gerar o seguinte objeto:

```js
{
  desColigada: "Empresa fulano de tal",
  codMatricula: "00555454",
  dataImpressao: "23/05/2016",
  arrayInformacoes: [
    {
      Data: "Mar 20, 2017 12:00:00 AM", 
      Atividade: " 23 GERAR", 
      Observação: "Processo cancelado por: Administrador - as", 
      Usuário: "afo"
     }
  ]
};
```